# Executing command on every file in folder in random order

Tags: shell, find, sort, random

I want to execute one command for every file in a folder, but randomly. Something like:

```
find . -type f -exec <command> '{}' \;
```

but every time in another order. This is closest to my needs, but 1) it doesn't work, 2) order is random, but always the same:

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -Rz | xargs -0 <command>
```

Comment: Do you realize that the same command will get run on every file, simply in a different order?

Comment: That command should work. What's wrong with it? Are you sure that the command isn't reordering the files? What's the output of `find . -type f -print0 | sort -Rz | xargs -0 echo`, does it change if you run it multiple times?

Comment: Hmm indeed... when I use `echo` command, it works as expected. But actually I want _<command>_ to be `mupdf` (I want to display images from folder in random order) - in that case it only displays randomly selected image and exits.

Same with executable script with only one command `echo "$1"` in it - only first file name is echoed.

When I use my first commandline: `find . -type f -exec <command> '{}' \;` , all images are displayed in sequence (when I close one image, next image is displayed), but not in random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec <command> '{}' \;
```

is not equivalent to

```
find . -type f | xargs <command>
```

observe:

```
$ find -type f
./b
./c
./e
./d
./a
$ find -type f -exec echo '{}' \;
./b
./c
./e
./d
./a
$ find -type f | xargs echo
./b ./c ./e ./d ./a
```

`xargs` collects a bunch of arguments up to a given length and then executes the command with all arguments at once.

This is what gets executed from `find -type f -exec echo '{}' \;`

```
echo ./b
echo ./c
echo ./e
echo ./d
echo ./a
```

This is what gets executed from `find -type f | xargs echo`

```
echo ./b ./c ./e ./d ./a
```

This works well for commands that can take multiple arguments like `md5sum` or `file`. But does not work for commands that only take one argument at a time.

To make `xargs` behave more like `find -exec` you can add argument `-n1` to `xargs`:

```
$ find -type f | xargs -n1 echo
./b
./c
./e
./d
./a
```

`-n1` tells `xargs` to execute a command for every `1` arguments.

In your example command:

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -Rz | xargs -0 -n1 <command>
```

---

Bonus: you can also make `find -exec` to behave more like `xargs` by closing the `-exec` with `\+` instead of `\;`:

```
find -type f -exec <command> '{}' \+
```